# Trying to identify proper rivet replacement

Tags: rivets

A leg broke on one of my tent poles, and I need to replace the rivet. Pop rivets don't seem to be the right option, so I'm asking for assistance in identifying the type of rivet in the other legs

[image: rivets in legs]

Comment: Looks like a plain brass rivet with counter sunk head.  The end is usually deformed by hammer or rivet setter.  Would use a counter sunk screw/bolt and a lock nut(cap nut).

Comment: I suggested a bolt/nut because I do not know if that housing will take kindly to a DIY rivet replacement.